# The subobject classifier is a set??

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading about subobject classifiers in presheaf categories, and got confused.

The book speaks of a subobject classifier $\Omega$ of the presheaf category $[P^{op}, Set]$, where $P$ is a poset having a largest element $T$. So, as I understand, $\Omega$ is an element of $[P^{op}, Set]$, meaning it is a contravariant functor from $P$ to $Set$.

But then a few lines later, the book says we can regard the truth values of the subobject classifier as a Heyting Algebra, and this induces a monoid structure on $\Omega$. The book goes on to speak of actions of this monoid on a set, all the while using notation like $\alpha \in \Omega$. In other words, it looks like they are saying $\Omega$ as a set.

My question is, how can $\Omega$ have any elements, if it is a functor? Are they writing $\Omega$ when they actually mean $\Omega$ applied to $T$? If this is the case then my confusion is (mostly) cleared.

Comment: Which book${}$?

Comment: a handout from my lecturer, I believe it's based off on Sheaves in Geometry and Logic: A First Introduction to Topos Theory.

Comment: $\Omega$ is an internal Heyting algebra, that is, it is naturally a presheaf of Heyting algebras on $P$. The Heyting algebra of truth values is indeed $\Omega(T)$. It's hard to tell without further details, but your monoidal actions might indeed be of this monoid.

Comment: In a topos, sometimes $a\in A$ means that $a$ is an arrow from the terminal object $1$ to the object $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "element" they mean "*global* element", then a global element (of $A$) is an arrow from $1\to A$ where $1$ is the terminal object. Since $T$ is the top element of the poset, it is the terminal object of that poset when viewed as a category. Since $\mathsf{Hom}$ is continuous in its second argument, we have that $\mathsf{Hom}(-,T)\cong 1$ where $1$ is the terminal object of the category of presheaves. A global element of the presheaf $P$ is an element of $$\mathsf{Nat}(1,P)\cong\mathsf{Nat}(\mathsf{Hom}(-,T),P)\cong P(T)$$ where $\mathsf{Nat}(F,G)$ is the set of natural transformations between $F$ and $G$, i.e. the hom-set of the category of presheaves. The second isomorphism is Yoneda. So the *global* elements of the presheaf $\Omega$ are in correspondence with the elements of the set $\Omega(T)$.

More naturally, we can use the notion of the internal language of an elementary topos which can be presented as the [Mitchell-Bénabou language](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mitchell-B%C3%A9nabou+language). This lets us write what looks like "normal" mathematics but interpret it into any elementary topos. In this context, global elements correspond to *closed* terms. In other words, the elements of $\Omega(T)$, in this case, correspond to the closed terms of type $\Omega$ in the internal language.